# XCode commits/pushes code to GitHub but stays hooked on commit sheet

Tags: xcode, git

When I commit/push my code to GitHub through the XCode interface everything works fine. (Code is committed/pushed) but XCode doesn't seem to get that and wait for somethings.

I have to cancel the commit (which was already done, so nothing happens) to get by to the code.

Am I the only one to have this problem ?

PS : XCode 5/Mavericks 10.9.1.

---

Edit : I doesn't seems to be clear : The git process works: Files are committed.  It's not a git problem.

Comment: Try going to the directory in Terminal and typing `git status` in that directory. What does it return?

Comment: Would you like me to move this to stack overflow?

Comment: As I said there are no problem with Git. It's XCode so I don't think SO is the right place :)

Comment: SO is the premium place for "**• software tools commonly used by programmers** _and_ **• practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development**" so it's clearly on topic there. It's also fine here if you wish to keep it here, but the eyeballs there are thousands as numerous.